# Is there an R function to rename one character value in a row in a dataset?

Tags: r, dataset

Consider this basic dataset:

```
myfruit <- tibble(fruit = c("apple", "orange", "apple", "pear", "banana"),
                  quantity = c("10","20","10","30", "40"))
```

Using R, how can I rename all values in the "fruit" column which display "apple" to "mango", without changing its associated "quantity" value? I know you can manually change the values but what is a more efficient method for larger datasets?

Any help would be much appreciated - many thanks,
Karima

Comment: `myfruit$fruit[myfruit$fruit == "apple"] <- "mango"`. I don't post as an answer because I bet that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the vectorized `ifelse` function here:

```
myfruit$fruit <- ifelse(myfruit$fruit == "apple",
                        "mango", myfruit$fruit)
```